# How to simulate absorption of fluid?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I would like to know how to simulate water being absorbed by a rectangular filter paper aligned vertically where the source of water is above it.

Comment: Are you using blender's fluid simulation engine? It allows one or more objects to be regarded as "outflow", i.e. deleting fluid. They must be big enough to collide correctly with your fluid elements, otherwise (especially with low resolution fluids) they will be almost ignored by the passing fluid.

Comment: I have never tried this, but the way I would do it is to have your domain cut off the water right when it touches your filter paper (so the water never actually touches it) Then for the second step, you would need to animate a white blotch growing over a black background (in After Effects etc.) then use the animation as a glossy map/mask for your filter paper. I can't think of any other way to do this.